# How to create a BarChart in pyqt5

Tags: python, sql, pyqt5

I have created a barchart using qchart. I want plot the total of males and females against their respective positions but the total does not correspond with the positions labels as shown in the image below.

Below is what I have done.

```
 def second_create_bar(self):
       
        male_barchart = ''' SELECT position, COUNT(*) AS Male_Count FROM employee WHERE gender='Male' GROUP BY position  '''

        male_barchart_sql = cur.execute(male_barchart).fetchall()

        series = QBarSeries()
        set0 = QBarSet("Male")

        for male in male_barchart_sql:

            set0 << male[1]
            series.append(set0)

        female_barchart = ''' SELECT position, COUNT(*) AS Female_Count FROM employee WHERE gender='Female' GROUP BY position  '''

        female_barchart_sql = cur.execute(female_barchart).fetchall()

        set1 = QBarSet("Female")
        for female in female_barchart_sql:
            set1 << female[1]
            series.append(set1)
  
          
        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Gender- Employee Positions Total ")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        categories = ["Auditor", "Clerk", "Directors", "Managers", "VOs"]
        axis = QBarCategoryAxis()
        axis.append(categories)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setAxisX(axis, series)

        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        chartView = QChartView(chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.ui.widget_321.setChart(chart)
```

[image]

Comment: And what would the expected result be? What are the exact values?

Comment: Well looking at the image above what am expecting is for example the total number of clerks should be where the clerks label is, it should not change to the Auditors or VOs. But my coding is mismatching the total with the position labels, assigning a particular total position to a different position label.

Comment: For now each position has a single record in the database. It might grow in future.